# How to calculate Received Signal Strength (RSS) and path loss Error in dB?

Tags: networking, rss, communication, wireless

supposed that the **measurement RSS** is "-70dBm" and the **predicted RSS** is "-68dBm, the **transmission power of antenna** is "-12dBm"，

then if the following equation is right? if not, how to calculate it?

**Error = |10 * log10 (70/12) - 10 * log10 (68/12)| = 10 * log10 (70/68)**

now my measurement is the **RSS in dBm**, how to convert it into **dB**?

Comment: Thanks to the editors. Here is the difference between RSS and RSSI[http://dinomycle.blogspot.com/2011/04/difference-between-rssi-and-rss.html]

Comment: Unfortunately "RSS" can mean many things. You've tagged your question with the RSS -tag (for questions about Really Simple Syndication). Your question would probably be better tagged with "Wireless". Then people who are experts in those areas could better find your question.

Comment: @janih thanks a lot. the RSS in here is the received signal strength of Wi-Fi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This often confuses folks in my experience, and as such warrants a thorough explanation.

The "m" in "dBm" means relative to 1 milliwatt.  It is typically used for absolute measurements, whereas "regular" dBs are typically used for power gains/losses/diffs.

```
Example:
in/tx   out/rx
1w      .5w

(1 milliwatt = 0.001)
10log(1/0.001) = 30dBm
10log(0.5/0.0001) = 27dBm
loss = 3dB


10log(1) = 0dB
10log(0.5) = 3dB
loss still is 3dB
(note there is an implied /1w here since the argument to log must be unit-less, e.g. 0.5w/1w = 0.5 "flat" (aka no units))

So in the context of power differences, the m does not matter.

Things to note:
1/2 of power lost == -3dB gain (or +3dB loss)
power gains/losses in series are added/subtracted when in dBs -vs- multipled/divided when in watts
0 watts == -infinity dB
0 dBm == 1 milliwatt
log here is base 10 (not 2 nor e)
reletiveGainOrLoss = 10^(valueOfGainOrLossInDb/10)
valueOfPowerInMilliwatts = 10^(valueOfPowerInDbm/10)


In your example, I'll presume by error you mean the error of the predicted loss relative measured loss:
predicted loss =
known transmission power - predicted RSS =
-12dBm - -68dBm = 
56dB

measured loss =
known transmission power - measured RSS =
-12dBm - -70dBm = 
58dB

error of predicted loss relative to measured loss =
|predicted loss - measured loss| = 
|56dB - 58dB| =
2dB (==2dBms, but for diffs we should drop the m) = 

Or more directly: 70 - 68 (so easy with dBs!)

This equates to a 63% error (or 58, depending on how it is done):
10^(-2dB/10) =
0.63
(10^(2dB/10) =
1.584893192461113

In millwatts:
10^(valueInDbm/10) =
10^(-70/10) = 0.0000001 milliwatts
10^(-68/10) = 0.000000158489319 milliwatts
10^(-12/10) = 0.063095734448019 milliwatts

As a sanity check:
(0.0000001/0.063095734448019 - 0.000000158489319/0.063095734448019) / (0.0000001/0.063095734448019) =
(0.000001584893192 - 0.000002511886428) / 0.000001584893192 = 
-0.000000926993236 / 0.000001584893192 =
-0.584893190707832
(note that doing it in watts is much more laborious! (not to even mention float errors))
```

To answer your other question regarding:

```
Error = |10 * log10 (70/12) - 10 * log10 (68/12)| = 10 * log10 (70/68)
```

The first equation is nonsensical; as discussed above: for dBs we add/subtract -vs- multiply/divide.  The second equation is however true, based on one of the rules of logs:

```
log a + log b = log ab
```

Answer (score 0):

When the **RSS** in **dBm**, the path loss is equal to the **difference** between the transmission RSS and received RSS, the **unit of path loss** in this case is **dB**.